# How to open specific page of paginate?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I get comments paginated. And I need to check, if I have the id of a comment, then open the page that comment is in. Here is my code:

```
public function show_comments(Request $request) {
   $cmnt_id = $request->input('cmnt_id');
   if ( isset( $cmnt_id ) ){
      // I need to get all comments paginated but start from the page that $cmnt_id is in it
   } else {
      // starts from page 1 
      $comments = Cmnt_tb::paginate(10);
   }
   return View('show_cmnts', compact('comments'));
}
```

How can I do that? any idea?

I think I have to make a new URL and redirect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but I guess something like this will work for you:

```
public function show_comments(Request $request) {
    $cmnt_id = $request->input('cmnt_id');
    $perPage = 10;
    if (isset($cmnt_id)){
        // Get row number.
        $rowNumber = Cmnt_tb::where('id', '<=', $cmnt_id)->count();
        // Get page.
        $page = ceil($rowNumber / $perPage);
        return redirect('show-comments-url?page='.$page);
    } else {
        $comments = Cmnt_tb::paginate($perPage);
        return view('show_cmnts', compact('comments'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, What's `show-comments-url` ? Should I define something new in `routes.php`? Or should I create a new controller?

Comment: @stack no, it's just url of the first page of the pagination (which is without `?page=2` part).

Comment: well I don't know how should I create `show-comments-url` .. I just know I shouldn't use `show-comments-url` literally. Should I make something like this? `http://example.com/...?page=1` ?

Comment: @stack yes. But I guess you could use some helper for that. If paginate route is named route, use it's name, like `return redirect(route('route.name').'?page='.$page);` This should generate real URL like `http://example.com/articels/comments?page=4`